# C++ (cilk plus code): Segmentation fault 11

Tags: c++, intel, cilk-plus, cilk

I downloaded Intel Parallel Studio and then went to the command and entered:

```
source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

followed by: `icpc file.cpp` to run a Cilk plus file.

The file.cpp is a simplified version of an original example used in cilkplus.org so it should work but it produces a segmentation fault

here's the file I'm trying to run using cilk plus compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int fib(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    int x = cilk_spawn fib(n-1);
    int y =  fib(n-2);
    cilk_sync;
    return x + y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 39;

    clock_t start = clock();
    int result = fib(n);
    clock_t end = clock();

    double duration = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Calculated in %.3f seconds using %d workers.\n", duration, __cilkrts_get_nworkers());


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fib(39) is quite a large number. What happened when you tried smaller arguments?

Comment: same Segmentation fault 11

Comment: Do you want us to guess what you tried?

Comment: i tried 11,9, 3

Comment: That narrows the problem down. Did you try 2? Did you try removing x? Or y? Or `cilk_sync`?

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the segfault happens.  (In what function, preferably what asm instruction.  Check the call stack, too, to see how deep it is.)  Then [edit] that info into the question, along with the fact that you tried some smaller `n` values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is 39.

The code looks right to me. While I have never worked with cilk, yet from what I get the code seems right considering you did copy it.

My guess would be 39 is a number too big. Try smaller or bigger numbers.

If it works, remove all the duration nonsense and try a loop for fib(i) for first 40 cases. Use the simpler version before you mess it up.

Comment: What cases did you try? Try 2?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're working in Cilk, I have had never heard of it until yesterday.